# DB2 embedded SQL in RPGLE

Tags: sql, db2, embedded, db2-400, rpgle

Lets assume we have this query:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.* INTO :DS1, :DS2 FROM FILE1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN FILE2 AS T2 ON T1.KEY = T2.KEY
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Everything comes up okay if both records are found. But what happens if FILE2 record is not present?

```
SQLCOD -305 THE NULL VALUE CANNOT BE ASSIGNED TO OUTPUT HOST VARIABLE
```

And even if the record from FILE1 is found, both DS are empty! That's a problem.
A way to overcome this is to use `COALESCE` on every field, but what if I've got hundreds of them?!
Another way is to use two distinct queries. But that's ugly if I want a cursor.

Is there a better way?

Comment: If either must be present, change your LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN

Comment: FILE2 record is not required. But FILE1 record is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have columns that could be NULL, then you have to pass in an integer variable to be used as a NULL indicator.  Then if the value for the result column is null, SQL puts a -1 in the indicator variable.

With a LEFT JOIN every column from the right table could be NULL.

The [manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzajp/rzajpindvar.htm) has the following example:

```
EXEC SQL
   SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(SALARY)
   INTO :PLICNT, :PLISAL:INDNULL
   FROM CORPDATA.EMPLOYEE
   WHERE EDLEVEL < 18
```

Note that there's no comma between the null-capable PLISAL and INDNULL.

When dealing with Data structures,  you can pass in an null indicator array.  So you code should be something like:

```
// xx should be the number of columns in T2
dcl-s indArr  int(5) dim(xx);

exec sql
  SELECT T1.*, T2.* INTO :DS1, :DS2 :indArr
  FROM FILE1 AS T1
    LEFT JOIN FILE2 AS T2 ON T1.KEY = T2.KEY
   FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

As an FYI: it's considered a bad idea to use `SELECT *` in production code.  You should an an explicit list of columns.  That way somebody can come along later and add a column to your table without breaking your code.

Comment: That was it! Awesome as always! And you're right about using single columns, but with 80 chars limitation, hundreds of fields become a bit tedious!

Comment: @LppEdd, it's not that difficult to generate a comma separated list of column names.  If nothing else, you can get a list or columns into a text editor and replace the CRLF with comma.